# IIS rewrite rule all to index.php except /edit directory

Tags: iis

Hello i am trying to make it so when i put in url /edit then put me in a directory /edit. Everything else is only in the index.php

```
<rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.js|\.css|\.ico|\.mp4|captcha.php|servertime.php|robots.txt)$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
```

Currently this code is redirecting everything to an index.php
When I add:

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 1-1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^edit/?(.*)$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="edit/index.php" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
```

The directory /edit opens but I lose the other redirect all to index.php

Answer (score 0):

You need a new "rule" just make sure you add it before the other rules :)

```
<rule name="rule1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^edit" />
    <action type="None" />
</rule>
```